# mongodb check in that there's one document in map function

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mapreduce, document

I am handling aggregated data (mapreduce), and when there's only one doc on the map function, it doesn't send it to reduce. Is there a way to check inside map that there's only one doc or force it through reduce?

**UPDATED**

As I posted below, the solution to this problem (although with a huge performance loss) is to always calculate the values in map, and add it to the emit object. If the emit passes through reduce than we overwrite the values with the proper group calculations else it will be output as calculated in map.

Comment: This is correct behavior - when there is only one document for a particular key it doesn't get sent to reduce - which is expected behavior.  Since there is only one emit, there is nothing to reduce.

Comment: hi asya. yeh, I know. the thing is that I'm creating new fields in reduce (based on some calculations) and since it doesnt pass through reduce when theres only one doc the fields are never created on the final output. I did find a workaroung which is creating that field on map and if it passes through reduce it will be overwritten else it will use what was created on map. but this creates huge overhead since I'm creating the field in every map... there should be a forceReduce of something similar, in my opinion

Comment: If you post your actual map/reduce functions, it's possible that a more effective "work-around" is available.

Comment: Andre: rather than updating the question with the answer inline, you should post your own answer below.  Perhaps someone will have other solutions to suggest in future.  It would also be helpful to share an example of your map/reduce function & workaround.